# Categorical Bubble Plot in Jqplot

Tags: plot, jqplot

Sorry if I don't speak English very well.

I want to draw an graphic like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840926/categorical-bubble-plot-for-mapping-studies) in **Jqplot**.

I know to create the two "independent graphics" but I want to join both graphics together.

Is it possible create this graphic?

Thanks.