# How to create a categorical bubble plot in Python?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot, bubble-chart

Looking for help to create a plot similar to one in this link, just using a python library.
[Catagorical Bubble Chart using ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840926/categorical-bubble-plot-for-mapping-studies): See the most up-voted response.

Here I borrowed the data from the link:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1':['Does.Not.apply',
                                'Not.specified',
                    'Active.Learning..general.',
                       'Problem.based.Learning',
                               'Project.Method',
                          'Case.based.Learning',
                                'Peer.Learning',
                                        'Other',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                                'Not.specified',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                    'Active.Learning..general.',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                       'Problem.based.Learning',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Project.Method',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                          'Case.based.Learning',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                                'Peer.Learning',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                                       'Other'],
                       'Var2':['Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                               'Does.Not.apply',
                                'Not.specified',
                                'Not.specified',
                    'Active.Learning..general.',
                    'Active.Learning..general.',
                       'Problem.based.Learning',
                       'Problem.based.Learning',
                               'Project.Method',
                               'Project.Method',
                          'Case.based.Learning',
                          'Case.based.Learning',
                                'Peer.Learning',
                                'Peer.Learning',
                                        'Other',
                                        'Other'],
                        'Count' : [53,15,1,2,4,22,6,1,15,15,1,1,2,2,4,4,22,22,6,6,1,1]})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#) is a grammer of graphics python implementation based on r's ggplot2.

The code is pretty much identical to the code in your R link.

```
import math
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame(<dataframe data here>)

df['dotsize'] = df.apply(lambda row: math.sqrt(float(row.Count) / math.pi)*7.5, axis=1)

(ggplot(df, aes('Var1', 'Var2')) + \
       geom_point(aes(size='dotsize'),fill='white') + \
       geom_text(aes(label='Count'),size=8) + \
       scale_size_identity() + \
       theme(panel_grid_major=element_line(linetype='dashed',color='black'),
             axis_text_x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0))
).save('mygraph.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's native [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) can of course create this kind of graph. It is just a categorical scatter plot with variable markersizes. Using your toy data set:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#create markersize column from values to better see the difference
#you probably want to edit this function depending on min, max, and range of values
df["markersize"] = np.square(df.Count) + 10
fig = plt.figure()
#plot categorical scatter plot
plt.scatter(df.Var1, df.Var2, s = df.markersize, edgecolors = "red", c = "white", zorder = 2)
#plot grid behind markers
plt.grid(ls = "--", zorder = 1)
#take care of long labels
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Regarding the definition of your markersize function for the scatter plot, [you might want to read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403507/8881141)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this problem would be to [plot an annotation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) with the value and a circle around it at each categorical point:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#create padding column from values for circles that are neither too small nor too large
df["padd"] = 2.5 * (df.Count - df.Count.min()) / (df.Count.max() - df.Count.min()) + 0.5
fig = plt.figure()
#prepare the axes for the plot - you can also order your categories at this step
s = plt.scatter(sorted(df.Var1.unique()), sorted(df.Var2.unique(), reverse = True), s = 0)
s.remove
#plot data row-wise as text with circle radius according to Count
for row in df.itertuples():
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle = "circle, pad = {}".format(row.padd), fc = "w", ec = "r", lw = 2)
    plt.annotate(str(row.Count), xy = (row.Var1, row.Var2), bbox = bbox_props, ha="center", va="center", zorder = 2, clip_on = True)

#plot grid behind markers
plt.grid(ls = "--", zorder = 1)
#take care of long labels
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Kudos to DavidG who showed me [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51284756/8881141) how to prevent that the annotation is printed outside the graph.